# Any way to Overwrite get_stock_quantity in my functions.php?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multisite

I am working in Wordpress Multisite and trying to ensure that all the stock info is fetched from the base site tables. I am trying to overwrite get_stock_quantity() woocomerce function in my theme's functions.php. What i found was

```
public function get_stock_quantity( $context = 'view' ) {
    return $this->get_prop( 'stock_quantity', $context );
}
```

Now this is neither a filter nor an action. I overwrote one filter that is

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity', 'wcs_custom_get_stock_quantity', 1, 2);

function wcs_custom_get_stock_quantity( $availability, $_product ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $productQuantity = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->base_prefix.'postmeta WHERE post_id = '.$_product->get_id() ." AND meta_key = '_stock'", OBJECT );
    return $productQuantity[0]->meta_value;
}
```

But woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity only works on the Products List page. The individual product-edit page uses get_stock_quantity.

How can I overwrite it without changing Core files?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to alter [`get_stock_quantity()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#353-361) method depends on the product. AS you have already notice looking at the source code you see that:

```
return $this->get_prop( 'stock_quantity', $context );
```

Now [`get_prop()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Data.html#600-623) method is a part of `WC_Data` class and has a generic filter hook:

```
$value = apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $prop, $value, $this );
```

And if you look to get_hook_prefix() method you have this:

```
return 'woocommerce_' . $this->object_type . '_get_';
```

For product variations the object_type is: `product_variation`
For other products  the object_type is: `product`
The `$prop` argument is `stock_quantity`

So know you can built the related filter hooks. Try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_stock_quantity( $value, $product ) {
    $value = 15; // <== Just for testing
    return $value;
}
```

So for product variations you use `woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity` filter hook.
And for the other cases `woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity` filter hook

Comment: ok I did that but i am facing same issue. The filters you wrote do exactly what mine was doing but i need to overwrite the stock quantity function of "Edit Product" page. At the moment, on products list table I am able to get the base site's stock quantity but on edit product page it shows the stock of its own table (Subsite Table) rather than fetching it from the base site's table.

Comment: @Omicans facing the same problem, looks like there is no chance hook in before to change the $contect to 'edit'.

Comment: @anibal Sorry but this is the WooCommerce official composite hook for `WC_Product` method `get_stock_quantity()` and it still work perfectly on last WooCommerce version. Note that this hook works only on "view" context for front end, but not as "edit" context in backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the database, but remember this code is executed one time each time you list your products, and when you update your product

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
    function custom_get_stock_quantity( $value, $product ) {
        $value = 15; // <== Just for testing
        //update dabatabase:
        update_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_stock', $value );
        return $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can use $product->set_stock($value); as well to set the value in database

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_stock_quantity' ,'custom_get_stock_quantity', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_stock_quantity( $value, $product ) {
    $value = 15; // <== Just for testing
    //update dabatabase:
   $product->set_stock($value);
    return $value;
}
```